# Query for my SSRS Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a query for which I would not like the case statements to be included in the Group By,
But it gives an error without them.
please it.

```
select res.bu_desc,res.product_desc,sum(partcount) as cnt,report_status from (
  select bu.bu_desc,prod.Product_desc, count(part_no) as partcount, 
   CASE 
     WHEN pd.created_date between '2012-08-01' and '2014-08-01' THEN 'New' 
      WHEN  s.Status_Id>=4 and s.Status_Id<8 THEN 'Backlog' 
        WHEN pd.analysis_complete_date  between '2012-08-01' and '2014-08-01'                      THEN            'Delivered'              
    END as report_status 
    from scn_part_details pd 
   left join scn_project_details prd on prd.project_id=pd.project_id 
left join scn_bu bu on bu.bu_id=prd.bu_id 
 left join SCN_Product_Name prod on prod.product_id=prd.product_id 
   left join [dbo].[SCN_CurrentStatus] as cs on cs.[Part_Id_Num]=pd.[Part_Id_Num] 
   left join [dbo].[SCN_Status] as s on cs.[Part_Status_Id]=s.Status_Id 
     where prd.group_id=1 and s.Status_Id not in (12)
         and pd.created_date between '2012-08-01' and '2014-08-01'
         and pd.analysis_complete_date  between '2012-08-01' and '2014-08-01'
    group by  prod.Product_desc,bu.bu_desc,s.Status_Id,pd.created_date,pd.analysis_complete_date
       having count(part_no) > 5) as res
             group by res.bu_desc,res.product_desc,report_status
                   group by res.bu_desc,res.product_desc,report_status
```

I just want a query for my ssrs reports, where I would get the part count which are created b/w the dates, part count which are not completed b/w the dates and part count which are successfully delivered.

I would like to display the reports in bar charts form.

The status are new, Backlog, delivered. And all the results are getting the status NEW in the query here, as the 1st case is applicable for all of them. i.e all of them are created. None of the results are going to 2nd and 2rd stage.

How to resolve this.?

Comment: What do you actually want? I don't understand what you are asking. Just on first glimpse: You only pseudo outer join, because with `prd.group_id=1 and s.Status_Id not in (12)` you remove all outer joined records and stay only with the inner-joined ones. To which table does part_no belong?

Comment: I just want a query for my ssrs reports, where I would get the part count which are created b/w the dates, part count which are not completed b/w the dates and part count which are successfully delivered.

The status are new, Backlog, delivered. And all the results are getting the status NEW in the query here, as the 1st case is applicable for all of them. i.e all of them are created. None of the results are going to 2nd and 2rd stage.

How to resolve this.?

Comment: You are asking: Are they created? If not: Are they backlog? If not: Are they completed? But you want: Are they completed? If not: Are they backlog? Else: they are new. So simply turn around your WHEN clauses.

Comment: And again: To which table does part_no belong?

Comment: part_no belongs to scn_part_details table.

Comment: I would like to find out, if created yes --> then backlog or delivered.? If no --> then they are new.

Comment: They are all created. It's in your WHERE clause.

Comment: Then what are your primary keys? How are the tables related? This would help a lot understanding your query.

Comment: Scn_part_details is my part details table in which part_no is the primary key, Scn_project_details table is my project details table in which Project_id is the primary key. Every project has one or more parts.

Comment: Okay, let us see if I get this straight: 1) In spite of its name, scn_part_details doesn't contain many detail records for one part, but it is the parts table with the primary key part_no. 2) Each scn_part_details has a Part_Id_Num, and many part_no can belong to one Part_Id_Num. So Part_Id_Num stands for a kind of super-part. 3) In spite of its name, SCN_CurrentStatus is actually the super-part table with the key Part_Id_Num, so that a record contains one super-part and its current status. 4) SCN_Status' primary key is Status_Id as the name suggests.

Comment: 5) In spite of its name, scn_project_details doesn't contain many detail records for one project, but it is the projetcs table with the primary key project_id. 6) SCN_Product_Name has the same key product_id, so this is a 1:1 relation and you only made this two tables for readability or such. 7) The table scn_bu is identified by bu_id, as the name suggests. It is a super table to the projects (scn_project_details); one scn_bu can have many projects.

Comment: true..Thorsten Kettner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all my assumptions made in your comments section surprisingly turned out to be right (even though I confused project and product), I can say the following:

1. You join each part in scn_part_details with their project (scn_project_details). This is one record per part.
2. You join each part in scn_part_details with their product (SCN_Product_Name). Still one record per part.
3. You join each part in scn_part_details with their super part status (SCN_CurrentStatus and then SCN_Status). Still one record per part.
4. You join each project with their bu (scn_bu). We are still with one record per part including its product, project, status und bu. (Well let's call bu a master project, as one bu has many projects.)
5. You group by product description. So this is *almost* like grouping by product. One would rather group by product_id. But well, let's assume there are no products with the same description.
6. You group by master project's description. Again, this is *almost* like grouping by bu_id. Again, let's assume that bu descriptions are unique.

Having said this: There are projects working on product parts and you want to see a list of master projects and products with the number of parts per status.

However there are some issues in your query (aside from grouping by descriptions instead of IDs):

- You want to see different statuses, but you are limiting your query in your where clause such that you only get delivered ones.
- Your case clause is wrong; it assumes all created parts are new. It must be turned upside down, so that it looks for delivered parts, then for backlock parts, then for new ones.
- Your left joins don't work, because you turn them into inner joins in your where clause by asking prd.group_id=1 and s.Status_Id not in (12).

As you are interested in products and projects I assume that you used left joins by mistake and want inner joins instead.

```
select 
  bu.bu_desc, 
  prod.product_desc, 
  case 
    when pd.analysis_complete_date  between '2012-08-01' and '2014-08-01' then 'delivered'              
    when  s.status_id >= 4 and s.status_id < 8 then 'backlog' 
    else 'new' 
  end as report_status,
  count(*) as partcount
from scn_part_details pd 
join scn_project_details prd on prd.project_id = pd.project_id and prd.group_id = 1 
join scn_bu bu on bu.bu_id = prd.bu_id 
join scn_product_name prod on prod.product_id = prd.product_id 
join scn_currentstatus cs on cs.part_id_num = pd.part_id_num
join scn_status s on cs.part_status_id = s.status_id and s.status_id not in (12)
where pd.created_date between '2012-08-01' and '2014-08-01'
group by 
  bu.bu_desc, 
  prod.product_desc, 
  case 
    when pd.analysis_complete_date  between '2012-08-01' and '2014-08-01' then 'delivered'              
    when  s.status_id >= 4 and s.status_id < 8 then 'backlog' 
    else 'new' 
  end;
```

Comment: This query looks good. But I would like to add one more constraint to it like, partcount should be greater than 5, Only then I need the result to be displayed. Where Can I add it.?

Comment: partcount is an aggregation (COUNT(\*) to be precise). If you want to constrain aggregation values then you must use HAVING after the GROUP BY clause: `GROUP BY bu.bu_desc, prod.product_desc, case ... end HAVING count(*) > 5;`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the inner `group by`? Can't you just do:

```
select 
  res.bu_desc,
  res.product_desc,
  count(partcount) as cnt,
  report_status 
from (select 
        bu.bu_desc,
        prod.Product_desc, 
        part_no, 
        CASE WHEN pd.created_date between '2012-08-01' and '2014-08-01' THEN 'New' 
             WHEN s.Status_Id>=4 and s.Status_Id<8 THEN 'Backlog' 
             WHEN pd.analysis_complete_date  between '2012-08-01' and '2014-08-01' THEN 'Delivered'              
        END as report_status 
      from scn_part_details pd 
      left join scn_project_details prd on prd.project_id=pd.project_id 
      left join scn_bu bu on bu.bu_id=prd.bu_id 
      left join SCN_Product_Name prod on prod.product_id=prd.product_id 
      left join [dbo].[SCN_CurrentStatus] as cs on cs.[Part_Id_Num]=pd.[Part_Id_Num] 
      left join [dbo].[SCN_Status] as s on cs.[Part_Status_Id]=s.Status_Id 
      where prd.group_id=1 and s.Status_Id not in (12)
      and pd.created_date between '2012-08-01' and '2014-08-01'
      and pd.analysis_complete_date  between '2012-08-01' and '2014-08-01'
     ) as res
  group by 
    res.bu_desc,
    res.product_desc,
    res.report_status
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply with query. This is my actual requirement. I just want a query for my ssrs reports, where I would get the part count which are created b/w the dates, part count which are not completed b/w the dates and part count which are successfully delivered.

The status are new, Backlog, delivered. And all the results are getting the status NEW in the query here, as the 1st case is applicable for all of them. i.e all of them are created. None of the results are going to 2nd and 2rd stage.

How to resolve this.?